# How to fix : The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it ? -Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a 5 second time bar to replace the wave. when wave1 has been 5 seconds it will move to wave2. then the first wave will be destroyed. when I got to wave3, an error came out. here's my code:

```
IEnumerator ChangeWave()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < wave.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        Destroy(wave[i]);
        wave[i+1].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

the error said The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. - unity
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How long is wave.Length?

Comment: Looks like your accessing a wave object somewhere that you already destroyed.
A simple wave[1] != null could help, but it will just prevent the error from happening, the underlying problem will be still there.
You should try to debug, maybe you have the same wave in your array twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.

1. Remove the -1 in the for loop, so it iterates to end
2. wave[i+1] will cause an error, so check if (i < wave.Length -1)
3. Destroy( array[index] ) will try and access Game Object but it's destroyed, so you should create a temporary var to hold gameobject, and set null to the array element.

Some fixes below - there might be a better way, but this is what I use:

**Version 1 - Using the above fixes**

```
IEnumerator ChangeWaveV2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < wave.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
        var t = wave[i];
        wave[i] = null;
        Destroy(t);

        if(i < wave.Length - 1)
            wave[i + 1].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

**Version 2 - A variation without needing to null out the element and create a temporary var. If you iterate from end to front of the array, you can freely Destroy() GameObjects in an array. May not be useful as it changes the wave array.**

```
IEnumerator ChangeWaveV3()
{
    System.Array.Reverse(wave);
    for (int i = wave.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
        Destroy(wave[i]);

        if(i > 0) 
            wave[i - 1].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```